# Breaking virtual invocation using new keyword and again starting a new virtual hierarchy

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual, overriding

Here is the code i got confused with.

```
 class foo
{
    public string fname;
    public virtual void print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am the boss i am the virtual");
    }
};


class bar : foo 
{

    public override void print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am the first derivative");   
    }
};


class tar : bar
{
    public new virtual void print()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("I am the newly born baby with a new keyword!!!!");
    }

};


class jar : tar
{
    public override void print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("i am created in derivative of tar i.e, jar");

    }

};  
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foo obj1 = new foo();
        obj1.fname = "neha";

        foo objtar = new jar();  //here lies the confusion why bar print() is called   
        objtar.print();
    }
}
```

In this code i am calling print method using 3rd level derived class(jar) object and base(foo). I am confused by looking at the output it is

> I am the first derivative

Can someone explain the reason behind it. I am a newb to c# need help....

Comment: You used the `new` keyword instead of override. Using `new` breaks the inheritance chain.

Comment: new is a tricky beast. try printing ((jar)objtar).print()

Comment: i know this can be done using jar obj = new jar(). But i am struck at the point of print() of jar being called why not foo print() is called here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you call `print` on an instance of `foo`. The `new` keyword will only be applied on typed instances of that type.

The rules of inheritance don't apply any more since `tar.print` is `new`.

This is all documented behavior which you can find on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx).

So this will work as you expected:

```
jar objtar = new jar();
objtar.print();
```

Comment: i know that but why first deived class method is being called? why not base class print() is called??

Comment: Because you're deriving from `bar`, not `foo`. The original inheritance chain is not influenced by `new`, you simply start a new chain. If declaring a virtual method with `new` had any effect in the base class, the writer of the `bar` class would have to design his class under the assumption that each `override` might or might not actually override - i.e. inheritance would be a mine field.

Comment: Simply because you have `override`n it. There is a major difference in `override` and `new`. `override` does follow inheritance.

Comment: @Cygon +1 for explaining the actual reason in simple terms.thanks

Comment: @PatrickHofman No patrick i got the point i was looking for virtual invocation chain will be broken once a new virtual method is added to chain that is why bar print() is getting called.